# Programming in Python using pygame

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I was just curious if someone could take a look at this code and explain to me why the walking_right images won't animate but the walking left will?  Also, I have a set of animations for standing still, what do you think would be the best way to implement this?  Lastly, I am trying to get a handle on OOP.  Is this doing ok or what other critiques would you suggest.  Thanks.

```
import pygame

WIDTH = 640
HEIGHT = 480
FPS = 100

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
GREY = (235, 235, 235)

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

import pygame
import character_tuple_list as tl
from settings import Settings

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        #Load in our sprite sheet with character data
        player_sheet = pygame.image.load(r'D:\Python Projects\Group Game\Character\Character 50x37.png').convert_alpha()
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(player_sheet, (50, 37))

        #Get our coordinates or screen and image
        gm_settings = Settings()
        gm_settings.screen_height
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        #Set image in the bottom middle of screen
        self.rect.centerx = 400 #center of rectangle
        self.rect.bottom = 470#pixels up from the bottom

        #Set the speed
        self.speedx = 0

        #Set Direction
        self.left = False
        self.right = False


        self.standing = []
        for image in tl.image_list_standing:
            self.standing.append(player_sheet.subsurface(image))    

        self.walking_right = []
        for image in tl.image_list_right:
            self.walking_right.append(player_sheet.subsurface(image))

        self.walking_left = []
        for inverse in self.walking_right:
            inverse = pygame.transform.flip(inverse, True, False)
            self.walking_left.append(inverse)    


    def update(self):

        gm_settings = Settings()
#        noi, time, current_image = 3,0,0
        pos_x = self.rect.x

        if self.right:
            frame = (pos_x // 30) % len(self.walking_right)
            self.image = self.walking_right[frame]
        if self.left:
            frame = (pos_x // 30) % len(self.walking_left)
            self.image = self.walking_left[frame]
        else:
            self.image = self.standing[0]

        self.speedx = 0 #Need these to make sure
        keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()


        if keystate[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.speedx = -1
            self.left = True
            self.right = False

        elif keystate[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.speedx = 1
            self.left = False
            self.right = True   

        else:
            self.right = False
            self.left = False

        self.rect.x += self.speedx

        #Set Walls for Width and Height
        if self.rect.right > gm_settings.screen_width:
            self.rect.rect = gm_settings.screen_width
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player()
all_sprites.add(player)


running = True
while running:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    all_sprites.update()
    screen.fill(GREY)
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is in the conditional group I quote bellow:

```
    if self.right:
        frame = (pos_x // 30) % len(self.walking_right)
        self.image = self.walking_right[frame]
    if self.left:
        frame = (pos_x // 30) % len(self.walking_left)
        self.image = self.walking_left[frame]
    else:
        self.image = self.standing[0]
```

See: if the character is not walking left (self.left), it will follow the else clause, and the standing image will be used. Even when the first `if` clause is followed (`self.right` is True), the image is reset to standing in this else clause.

Just change the `if self.left:` line to `elif self.left:` - that will prevent the else clause to be entered when `self.right` is True.

I will skip comments on the OO aspects at this time, as those would be too broad - but this code is not bad at all. One's attention is caught by the fact the  `update` method calls pygame's `get_pressed` directly - since there won't be  a lot of sprites simultaneously in need of the keyboard input, you could create another "update_movement" method that would take the vector returned by `get_pressed` as  a parameter, and be called explicitly from the main loop -  that would decouple your class from pygame's keyboard specifics, and would even free your character to be machine or network controlled.

Comment: Thanks, this is awesome!! Sorry for the too broad of question!